# Why is the alert, within an if statement, not closing when I click ok?

Tags: javascript, alert

I'm programming a learner test, using checkboxes. Functional requirements, per the client, are that the learner must score 100% to pass. The learner gets 3 attempts to pass and then must start the course over at the beginning. After each of the first 2 wrong selections, the learner is sent back to the first question of the test; "#vidQ1".

So far, I have a 'wrong answer' alert that tells the user that they made a wrong selection and how many attempts they have left. This is done as soon as the user makes a wrong selection. It doesn't wait for a submit event. The alert is correctly displaying the message and the decremented 'attempt' variable value and is also logging the new attempt value to the console.

The problem is that the alert does not close when the 'OK' button is clicked. But the 'attempt' variable is decremented each time the 'OK' button is clicked and the new value is logged to the console. I can only close it by closing the entire window. So the function is stopping at the alert, and I don't know why.

```
var attempt = 3;

    ...
    $('#ques01_b').click(function() {
     if( $(this).is(':checked')) {                   
        attempt --; 
        console.log(attempt);
        alert("That is incorrect.  You have this many attempts left: " +attempt);}      
        $("#vidQ01").focus();
      });
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/frankmix/h86n93bx/38/

Description: 
The javascript in the Fiddle is a portion of the 'loadvideos.js' file I created and the checkbox icon manipulation used for custom check marks.

The JavaScript in the Fiddle is for the loading and playing back of ONE of total of 30 questions and accompanying video simulations, each with 3 checkboxed responses to choose from, into a single div (#vidContainer).

I recently added the var attempt = 3 (today).

When the correct checkbox is selected, the video simulation plays. When the video ends, the first question and possible answers fadeout and the next question and possible answers fades in, and when the learner selects the correct answer for the next question, the first video displays none, and the next video loads and plays, and so on, for 30 videos.

Each question is in its own fieldset, and each fieldset contains 3 checkbox containers div's, for the 3 choices, that allow for the custom checks (green checks for correct selections and red x's for wrong ones).

There is only the first question here. The correct response is A (the checkbox input id="ques01_a")

Below the function that fires when the correct selection is made is my initial attempt at handling a wrong choice' B, in this case (the checkbox input id="ques01_b")

Below that is the checkbox icon manipulation code for the first question

Everything works and is 508 compliant as well to this point.

I'm now trying to add functions for counting and handling wrong answers; starting at LINE 20 in the JS part of this fiddle. That is where I'm asking for  your help at.

Sorry this is so wordy. I wanted to spare you all of that :)
Thanks again.

Comment: You have not given us enough information to assist you.  With what you posted, we can not reproduce this.  Please feel free to create a jsfiddle in order to convey your your small application.

Comment: will do, thank you

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work

Comment: Sounds like to me you are binding the click event multiple times and multiple alerts are opening up.

Comment: @epascarello That sounds like what I'm experiencing. I probably need a different approach. I will to need to add a handler for when var attempts =0. Do I need to add a comparison first; if attempts not equal to 0, then the alert with the remaining number of attempts. What might that look like? Thank you.

Comment: How is the click event added? Need to see more code.

Comment: It is added as a function. The function captures the current checkbox input, $(this) ,being selected. The alert fires as the 3rd statement in the 'if' function that is pasted in my original post.